# How do I get Magento to display configurable product prices on attribute selection?

Tags: php, javascript, magento

I have a store which has a configurable product. Unfortunately when a color options is selected, the prices displays as 0.00$.

You can see here:

http://beautysense.ca/brands/jane-iredale/jane-iredale-lips/jane-iredale-puregloss-for-lips-1181.html

I assume php is calling the wrong price from the database, but any other insight would be greatly appreciated.

FYI the price displays correctly when the item has been added to the cart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 JavaScript errors that are preventing the configurable product JS to run properly.

```
var j2t_point_default_point_unit_base = "<span class="price">$0.05</span>";
```

Quotes are invalid in the above code.

```
checkJ2tCloneText();
```

The above function is not defined when called.

`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'jqTransform'`

jQuery plugin is not loaded or cannot be accessed.

If you correct these Javascript errors, your price will display properly.